# Will jQuery be able to select this ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have an index.html file with an internal script that appends a textarea to the DOM when a radio button is checked.

I have an external script that gets the value of that textarea when a form is submitted and sends it as a form param. All my other form params are showing up correctly in the HTTP headers, however, this form param shows up as "undefined".

Is jQuery not allowed to select an element by ID when that element has been appended after the page was loaded? Should I be using the visibility property instead?

Comment: Can you post any JS/jQuery code for us to look at?

Comment: There is no difference between the just added and initially existed nodes from DOM perspective.

Comment: if the object has been added to the DOM then you can select it using jQuery. Perhaps you have a typo in your select? or you haven't appended it to the DOM yet? Code would be useful

Answer (score 0):

Jquery is able to do what you seems to try too.

```
   $("#outer").append("<textarea id=inserted>Shazam !</textarea>");
   /* ... do some stuff ... */
   alert($("#inserted").val()); // popup with "Shazam !"
```

You should post an example for a better answer.